# Conscientious vs Principled

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that describes a person who takes doing right by other seriously.

I like *principled* but for me it can connote an adherence to a doctrine and the person I am thinking of follows their own sense of right and wrong. I can also associate stubbornness and close-mindedness with principled people and this is not what I wish to imply.

I also like *conscientious*, but this word can also imply attention to detail.

The word I'm looking for describes a person that cares about doing right because of the impact it has on people, not service to some moral code.

Comment: Something beyond *ethical*?

Comment: That's a good question. Maybe I'm looking to avoid words like moral and ethical because of their association with religion. The context here is a person being asked to self-describe their qualities. Even if he is religious, my take on religion is that you are not supposed to boast of your devotion, so I want to steer clear of all that.

Comment: How is *ethical* associated with religion?

Comment: I guess I make the association because they both pertain to standards of moral conduct.

Comment: "Conscientious" doesn't imply "doing right".  One could easily be a "conscientious bigot".

Comment: What @HotLicks said (except that a bigot could have principles also, even though a non-bigot might not agree with them). *Conscientious* just means being careful.

Comment: "doing right because of the impact it has on people" *is* a moral code...

Comment: "a person that cares about doing right because of the impact it has on people" is observing a moral code, humanism, of a variety determined by what is considered "right" and why.

Comment: JEL and Lamar Latrell; is there no allowance for a distinction between a self-guided moral code (this is what attracted me to "conscience") vs adopting an external code? I'm thinking of how Huck Finn grappled with how the external code conflicted with his own ideas, and I'm looking for the word that described the person that follows his internal compass rather than complies with society's expectations of good character.

Comment: Thank you all for this. I passed this along and it turns out I posed the question incorrectly. I thought that the motivation for "doing the right thing" was impact it would have on others, but I was surprised that when we reviewed the different answers he objected to that motivation preferring "because it's the right thing to do." I'm going to choose Altruistic because I felt it was the best fit for the question as stated, but I think the overall discussion was much better than any one word. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this person may be described as being *altruistic* or possessing traits of [*altruism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altruism). This term has only one meaning, isn't associated with one's morality, and refers to somebody who “cares about doing right because of the impact it has on people.” Per Merriam-Webster:

> feelings and behavior that show a desire to help other people and a lack of selfishness

Comment: Unfortunately, "altruism" has been tainted somewhat by Objectivism, and may be misinterpreted.

Comment: I didn't know that, but looking into it Ayn Rand positioned Altruism as the opposite of Objectivism, yes?

Comment: If altruism were fundamentally bad, it would be very unlikely to have survived as a common trait of many species as long as it has. Also: Ayn Rand... just sayin'...

Answer (score 2):

You could say that they are **[honorable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honorable)**.

When used in conjunction with a title this tends to mean someone who is prestigious or highly placed (e.g. *the Honorable Judge Stevens*, but when used to describe a person's character, it means that they act rightly, and are fair and ethical in their dealings with others.  This also appears in conjunction with professions, as a way to suggest that doing the job is helpful to society and other people, not just a way to make money, as in *"He wanted an honorable profession, so he became an oncologist. "*

Comment: This was one of the words I considered; however, being *honorable* is associated with a sense of virtue and ethicality, which the asker does not want.

Comment: I actually have a problem with that part of the question, because the whole notion of "doing right" but without any reference to any form of morality really doesn't sense. It's really not possible to have a sense of right and wrong which is not based in morality of some sort. I assumed he was referring to a specific formally recognized moral code, such as a religion. Based on his later comments it looks like he recognized that the original question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

A [virtue ethicist](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/), would simply call them ***ethical***.

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> Virtue ethics is currently one of three major approaches in normative
>   ethics. It may, initially, be identified as the one that **emphasizes
>   the virtues, or moral character**, in contrast to the approach which
>   emphasizes duties or rules (deontology) or that which emphasizes the
>   consequences of actions (consequentialism).

This (might?) get around the close-mindedness of 'principled' (deontology) and the moral code of conscientious right-doing (consequentialism).

Have a sniff around the Greek word [Eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia) also...

Plato:

> The good composed of all goods; an ability which suffices for living
>   well; perfection in respect of virtue; resources sufficient for a
>   living creature.